# Refactor Func and Action

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a sample test methods: first with return value and second void. How refactor this duplicates in the method body?

```
Func method:  

 public Tout Execute<T1,T2, Tout>(Func<T1, Tout > func)
    {
    try{


            var service = CreateService<T1, T2>();

            try
            {
                Tout response = func(service);
                service.Close();
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                service.Abort();
                throw;
            }
    }
    }
```

Action method:

```
public void Execute<T1,T2>(Action<T1> action)
    {
    try{


            var service = CreateService<T1, T2>();

            try
            {
                action(service);
                service.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                service.Abort();
                throw;
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Because `<void>` is illegal there is no easy way. But I also don't see a need. As you say, these are 'test' methods. Do you have a real use-case?

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the `Action` in a `Func`:

```
public void Execute<T1,T2>(Action<T1> action)
{
     Execute<T1, T2, object>(a => { action(a); return null; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely not the answer you expected to here, but what about having "service" implement IDisposable? Then you can get rid of the try..catch by using(var service =..){...}. Dispose could call Abort if the service has not yert been closed.